# Two distributions with inverse distance closer than distance

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $F$ and $G$ are two distributions with a support, say $[0,1]$. Assume they are continuous and increasing. When we use the Kolmogorov distance $$\operatorname{dist}(F,G)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|F(x)-G(x)|,$$
What kind of relationship can we find between the distance and inverse distance?
$$\operatorname{dist}(F,G) \text{ and } \operatorname{dist}(F^{-1},G^{-1})$$
Can there be an example that shows inverses are a lot closer than the just the distance of $F$ and $G$?

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by changing some
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) code of your post. It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. It looks better :)

Comment: Do you want to modify the distance $\mathrm{dist}(F^{-1},G^{-1})$ to us the intersection of the domains of $F^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$.  If not, your written definition of distance only inspect the part that is in $[0,1]$.  Also, what is the distance if $\mathrm{supp}(F^{-1}) \cap \mathrm{supp}(G^{-1}) = \varnothing$?

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I'd say $F$ and $G$ are strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assume $F$ and $G$ are both continuous functions from $\left[0,1\right]$ to $\left[0,1\right]$, there is no guaranteed order relation between $\text{dist}(F,G)$ and $\text{dist}(F^{-1},G^{-1})$.

Consider a simply example, where
$$
F(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
kx,&x\in\left[0,\alpha\right]\\
\frac{1-k\alpha}{1-\alpha}\left(x-\alpha\right),&x\in\left(\alpha,1\right]
\end{array}
\right.\quad\text{and}\quad G(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
kx,&x\in\left[0,\beta\right]\\
\frac{1-k\beta}{1-\beta}\left(x-\beta\right),&x\in\left(\beta,1\right]
\end{array}
\right..
$$
Here the parameters $k>0$, $0<\alpha,\beta<1$ are chosen such that both $F$ and $G$ are increasing on $\left[0,1\right]$.

With this example, take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ close to $1$, and $k$ close to $0$. The image of $F$ and $G$ would then be similar to the following figure, where $\text{dist}(F,G)$ is obviously very large but $\text{dist}(F^{-1},G^{-1})$ is kind of small.

[image]

likewise, take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ close to $0$, and $k$ much larger than $1$. In this case, the image of $F$ and $G$ would be close to the following figure, where $\text{dist}(F,G)$ is kind of small but $\text{dist}(F^{-1},G^{-1})$ is obviously very large.

[image]